# why does the compiler declare a class method deleted?

Tags: c++, oop

i'm trying to make a class which include `std::pair` container, see the code bellow.

- why did the compiler declare a class method deleted?
- how to fix this issue?

```cpp
template <typename Kty_, typename Dty_>
class TreeNode {
public:

    // tags:
    using usI             = unsigned short int;                    
    using value_type      = std::pair<const Kty_, Dty_>;           
    using pointer         = value_type*;  
    using reference       = value_type&; 
    using const_reference = const value_type&; 



    TreeNode(
        const_reference             pairValue,
        usI                         height  = 0,
        TreeNode<const Kty_, Dty_> *parent  = nullptr,
        TreeNode<const Kty_, Dty_> *left    = nullptr,
        TreeNode<const Kty_, Dty_> *right   = nullptr
    ) {
        left_       = left;
        parent_     = parent;
        right_      = right;
        pairValue_  = pairValue;  // 48 // Overload resolution selected deleted operator '=' ​clang:ovl_deleted_oper
        height_     = height;
    }
protected:
    TreeNode<const Kty_, Dty_> *left_;
    TreeNode<const Kty_, Dty_> *parent_;
    TreeNode<const Kty_, Dty_> *right_;
    
    value_type                  pairValue_;
    usI                         height_;
};
```

- there is a set of [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2280?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DRU-RU%26k%3Dk(C2280)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=msvc-170) which call this issue:

  - *Example: Uninitialized data members:* it doesn't work for me because i don't know how to initialize `Kty_` & `Dty_` by their default values
  - *Example: Reference and const data members:* i have tried to remove some of `const` keyword specifies, but it doesn't help
  - *Example: Movable deletes implicit copy:* not my case i think
  - *Example: Indirect base members deleted:* not my case i think
  - *Example: Variant and volatile members:* not my case i think

Comment: What is the exact wording of the error message you receive? Which class method is deleted?

Comment: @joergbrech,
1. error: use of deleted function ‘std::pair& std::pair::operator=(const std::pair&)’
2. `std::pair`
3. https://onlinegdb.com/OXPDd3AzJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why did the compiler declare a class method deleted?

Because `const` members cannot be assigned to, `value_type pairValue_;` contains a const member.

> how to fix this issue?

Initialize `const` members properly.

One cannot assign to constant members in the constructor's body, which is what you were doing, just move the "initialization" (or rather all of them) to the initializer list.

```
TreeNode(const_reference pairValue, usI height = 0,
         TreeNode<const Kty_, Dty_> *parent = nullptr,
         TreeNode<const Kty_, Dty_> *left = nullptr,
         TreeNode<const Kty_, Dty_> *right = nullptr)
    : left_(left),
      parent_(parent),
      right_(right),
      pairValue_(pairValue),
      height_(height) {}
```

Comment: is it true that the use `initializer list` is this a good c++ practice?  Should I prefer this default option in the usual practice of writing code in c++, or does it still depend on the task?

Comment: @getsuga . Yes, you should use initialized lists whenever possible. Even better might be in-place initializes if the value does not depend on ctor's arguments.